# What does the L flag do in a yarn dev command

Tags: docker

I was just going through the docker-compose.dev.yml file in a nodejs boilerplate project [HERE](https://github.com/danielfsousa/express-rest-boilerplate/blob/main/docker-compose.dev.yml) and came across the following lines of code :-

```
version: "2"
services:
  boilerplate-api:
    command: yarn dev -- -L
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

I really cannot find any documentation for the -- -L flag and what it does. Would appreciate if somebody could shed some light on this.

There seems to be no such options on the yarn website [HERE](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/add) too.

P.S.

The file gets used in a command in the package.json file like so:-

```
 "docker:dev": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dev` command that yarn runs is defined like this in package.json

```
"dev": "nodemon ./src/index.js"
```

The `-- -L` notation means that the `-L` option is passed to the command run, so the actual command run is

```
nodemon ./src/index.js -L
```

The -L option for nodemon means that it should use 'legacy watch'. I'm not exactly sure what that is, but hopefully this is enough to explain what's going on.

Comment: enough indeed. thanks !!

Comment: can u attach any documentation , not needed , but would be helpful

Comment: I tried to look, but I can't really find any. Sorry.

Comment: thats cool np. I'll see if i can find it myself !

Comment: Anyone from the future looking for a reason. [Here is why](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting)